# A Clojure Spec for a set with falsey values in them

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

For some reason the below spec does say that `false` isn't a valid `::a-thing` even though it is part of the given set.

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as spec])

(spec/def ::a-thing #{:a :b :c false})

(spec/valid? ::a-thing :a)     ; => true
(spec/valid? ::a-thing :d)     ; => false
(spec/valid? ::a-thing false)  ; => false
```

Answer (score 5):

This is nothing to do with `spec`, and everything to do with how sets behave as functions. You will get similar misunderstandings whenever you use a set as a function to test for membership.

When you pass `spec` a *function*, it uses it as a predicate. Sets are functions, as is anything else that implements [`clojure.lang.IFn`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html). As functions, sets behave as identities on their members. All else follows. **Sets are in no way treated specially by `spec`**.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that falsey things aren't allowed in sets given to Spec
as it uses the set itself as a function to check for membership rather than
the `contains?` function. As we can see below a set will return the
given argument if it is a member of the set and nil otherwise.

```
(#{:a :b :c false} :a)    ; => :a
(#{:a :b :c false} false) ; => false
(#{:a :b :c false} :d)    ; => nil
```

This of course is the cause of the misunderstanding.

We have to manually wrap the set in a `contains` ourselves in order to get the spec working properly.

```
(spec/def ::a-thing #(contains? #{:a :b :c false} %))
```

Comment: Not so. Falsey things are allowed - they just don't produce the results you expected. This is so wherever sets containing falsey values  are used as predicates, whether by `spec` or elsewhere.

Comment: A distinction without a difference. Sets shouldn't be used as predicates. It is the fault of the Spec Guide for instructing the user to use sets as predicates, not the user for using them.

Comment: @Rovanion This is by no means reason to discourage use of sets as spec predicates in general. Your question is about a corner case only applicable to sets that contain `nil` or `false` – something rarely seen in practice.

Comment: I agree that [the spec Guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_predicates) is at fault. But `spec` itself is not. The phrase *"apart from `nil` or `false`"* in the right place would fix it.